# Why does my switch statement not respond to half of the cases?

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning and playing arround with C++ and I wanted to find how come my switch statement only responds to a half of the cases? It only responds when substracting from the integers. Note, that I am as much as a beginner as it is possible to be, so any advice would be really helpful.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77
#define SPACE_BAR 32

void startingCoord (int & x, int & y)
{
    cout << "Starting coord" <<endl;
    cin >> x >> y;
}
void printGrid(int x, int y)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            if (a + 1 == x && b + 1 == y)
            {
                cout<<" 0 ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<" - ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main ()
{
    int c = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    startingCoord(x, y);
    while (true)
    {
        printGrid(x, y);
        switch (c = getch()){
        case SPACE_BAR:
            return 0;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            x++;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            y++;
        case KEY_UP:
            x--;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            y--;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
        cout<<x<<" "<<y;

    }
}
```

Comment: for starters you should have `break;` after each `case` that doesn't `return`

Comment: [Get a good beginners book (or two)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and start over.

Comment: And [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If ytou stepped through the code line by line in a debugger you would have seen the problem immediately. Then you should go to your books to read and understand why it behaves like it does.

Comment: I meant that it only responds to the cases which contain a substraction (in this case the ones, where the user inputs the up arrow key or the left one)

Comment: And as @Someprogrammerdude explained, 30 seconds in the debugger stepping through the code would tell you *exactly* why that's what's happening. Literally 30 seconds. It's never too early to learn how to use a debugger, which is one of the best tools a coder has available to them.

Answer (score 7):

Change this:

```
case KEY_DOWN:
    x++;
```

to this:

```
case KEY_DOWN:
   x++;
   break;
```

and do the same for every case that doesn't have a `return` statement.

Without the `break` statement, the control flow continues to the cases after the case that its condition was just satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Like [@gsamaras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077909/4603538) said, you need to include a `break` statement at the end of each case unless your case `returns` something or you want the control flow to keep going.

Let me give you an example.

In your case, if you select `KEY_DOWN`, it will do the following:

```
switch (c = getch()) { // assume c = KEY_DOWN
    case SPACE_BAR: // is the value of c SPACE_BAR? no
        return 0;
    case KEY_DOWN: // is the value of c KEY_DOWN? yes
        x++; // do this
    case KEY_RIGHT: // no break, keep going
        y++; // do this
    case KEY_UP: // no break, keep going
        x--; // do this
    case KEY_LEFT: // no break, keep going
        y--; // do this
    default: // no break, keep going
        return 0; // returns 0
}
```

Similarly, if you'd press `KEY_RIGHT`:

```
switch (c = getch()) { // assume c = KEY_RIGHT
    case SPACE_BAR: // is the value of c SPACE_BAR? no
        return 0;
    case KEY_DOWN: // is the value of c KEY_DOWN? no
        x++; 
    case KEY_RIGHT: // is the value of c KEY_RIGHT? yes
        y++; // do this
    case KEY_UP: // no break, keep going
        x--; // do this
    case KEY_LEFT: // no break, keep going
        y--; // do this
    default: // no break, keep going
        return 0; // returns 0
}
```

For the two cases above, the result was the same: it returns 0 because the very last case (`default`) is `return 0;`

### What you should be doing

```
switch (c = getch()) { // assume c = KEY_DOWN
    case SPACE_BAR: // is the value of c SPACE_BAR? no
        return 0;
    case KEY_DOWN: // is the value of c KEY_DOWN? yes
        x++; // do this
        break; // there's a break, stop here.
    case KEY_RIGHT: 
        y++; 
        break; 
    case KEY_UP:
        x--; 
        break;
    case KEY_LEFT:
        y--;
        break;
    default: 
        return 0; 
}
```

### Implementing what you just learned

Now that we know that unless there's a break, the flow will keep going, we can use that to our advantage by moving `case SPACE_BAR:` above `default:` because we know that they both return 0 anyways:

```
switch (c = getch()) { 
    case KEY_DOWN: 
        x++;
        break;
    case KEY_RIGHT: 
        y++; 
        break; 
    case KEY_UP:
        x--; 
        break;
    case KEY_LEFT:
        y--;
        break;
    case SPACE_BAR: 
    default: 
        return 0; 
}
```

***Note**: While adding `case SPACE_BAR:` on top of the default is indeed a better idea than leaving them both separately, you can also just **not** put `case SPACE_BAR` at all, since even if you don't include it, it will fall into the `default` anyways.*

Good luck!